# Deploy to Heroku PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, reactjs, devise

In short I have a Rails API with Devise, and I want to deploy it to Heroku so I can use the json files in a React app. When I'm trying to migrate it to Heroku it's giving me the error:

"PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" of relation "reviews" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "reviews" ADD "user_id" integer"

Someone told me to remove the migration files, because somehow Devise already made them and the migration files would make them double?? Eitherway it doesn't help.

I'm not sure if you need it, but this is what my schema file looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160719152952) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text   "description"
    t.integer  "review_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "games", ["review_id"], name: "index_games_on_review_id", using: :btree

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "game_id"
  end

  add_index "reviews", ["game_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_game_id", using: :btree
  add_index "reviews", ["user_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                             default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",                default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                     default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                     null: false
    t.string   "authentication_token",   limit: 30
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "games", "reviews"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "games"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "users"
end
```

Comment: Seems like you have a migration to add user_id in reviews table

Comment: Yes earlier it gave me an error that it couldn't find the user_id, and I made a migration to add user to review, because the review belongs to a user. Back then it did solve the problem, but it wasn't the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes my guess is the the migrations are duplication and therefore running twice, which throws the error, because the indexed column already exists.

You can not use the migration files to reach your DB schema end point, by running something like instead;

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

See if this works.

Also though - this is a bit strange;

```
add_foreign_key "reviews", "users"
```

Did you add this via a migration? I don't normally do this for relations, the below being sufficient.  See if you can remove the add_foreign as well, as the index is sufficient in my view ( could be wrong sorry ).

```
add_index "reviews", ["user_id"]
```